# Flash photo album on website?

Tags: flash, web

I'm designing my own website where I want to quickly organize photos into categories. Any recommendation on flash-based photo album (better free) that I can effortlessly insert into my website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here:

http://djdesignerlab.com/2010/03/16/25-most-popular-free-flash-xml-photo-galleries/

there are plenty of free galleries